# Rails 3: how to test models that use an acts_as-style plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I've written a very simple plugin (following the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html)) that adds a `has_sex` method to `ActiveRecord::Base`, which, when called, adds a few instance methods (for getting appropriate pronouns and so on) to the model and `validates :sex, inclusion: {in: %w(male female)}`.

How should I write unit tests on models that utilise this?

I could test that `Person < HasSex::InstanceMethods`, which will be true if `has_sex` was called on Person (and the plugin tests ensure that the desired behaviour results). But I wonder if this is really testing implementation and not behaviour?

On the other hand, I could test if `Person.sex` only allows values 'male' and 'female', and that the various instance methods have the desired effect, but then I'm duplicating tests that I wrote for the plugin itself.

What's the best approach here? For the record, I'm testing with Test::Unit and Shoulda, but I'm more interested in the principle rather than the finer details.